# Compile WebRTC on Ubuntu 14.04 32bit

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, webrtc

I tried to compile WebRTC using  [the instruction](https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/)  on the official site. When I enter command `ninja -C out/Debug`, I get a huge error listing. I guess, it is senseless to provide the whole listing, but there are several occurrence of this string:

`../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++: 1:
../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++:
Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Clang's version on my machine:

`$ clang --version
Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)
Target: i386-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix`

I have no idea what to do. Can anybody help me, please?

UPD. The whole error listing:

`` $ ninja -C out/Debug
ninja: Entering directory `out/Debug'
[3/2955] CXX obj/webrtc/modules/remote_bitrate_estimator/remote_bitrate_estimator.remote_bitrate_estimator_abs_send_time.o
FAILED: ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -MMD -MF obj/webrtc/modules/remote_bitrate_estimator/remote_bitrate_estimator.remote_bitrate_estimator_abs_send_time.o.d -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -DCLD_VERSION=2 -DEXPAT_RELATIVE_PATH -DWEBRTC_POSIX -DWEBRTC_LINUX -DWEBRTC_INCLUDE_INTERNAL_AUDIO_DEVICE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=259396-1 -DUI_COMPOSITOR_IMAGE_TRANSPORT -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_PANGO=1 -DUSE_CAIRO=1 -DUSE_DEFAULT_RENDER_THEME=1 -DUSE_LIBJPEG_TURBO=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DUSE_CLIPBOARD_AURAX11=1 -DENABLE_ONE_CLICK_SIGNIN -DENABLE_WEBRTC=1 -DENABLE_MEDIA_ROUTER=1 -DENABLE_PEPPER_CDMS -DENABLE_CONFIGURATION_POLICY -DENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS -DENABLE_HIDPI=1 -DENABLE_TOPCHROME_MD=1 -DUSE_UDEV -DFIELDTRIAL_TESTING_ENABLED -DENABLE_TASK_MANAGER=1 -DENABLE_EXTENSIONS=1 -DENABLE_PDF=1 -DENABLE_PLUGINS=1 -DENABLE_SESSION_SERVICE=1 -DENABLE_THEMES=1 -DENABLE_AUTOFILL_DIALOG=1 -DENABLE_BACKGROUND=1 -DENABLE_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_BASIC_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_PRINT_PREVIEW=1 -DENABLE_SPELLCHECK=1 -DENABLE_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_DETECTION=1 -DENABLE_APP_LIST=1 -DENABLE_SETTINGS_APP=1 -DENABLE_SUPERVISED_USERS=1 -DENABLE_MDNS=1 -DENABLE_SERVICE_DISCOVERY=1 -DV8_USE_EXTERNAL_STARTUP_DATA -DFULL_SAFE_BROWSING -DSAFE_BROWSING_CSD -DSAFE_BROWSING_DB_LOCAL -DBWE_TEST_LOGGING_COMPILE_TIME_ENABLE=0 -DUSE_LIBPCI=1 -DUSE_OPENSSL=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_NSS_CERTS=1 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DWTF_USE_DYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS=1 -D_DEBUG -Igen -I../.. -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-strict-overflow -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wthread-safety -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Werror -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fvisibility=hidden -pipe -fPIC -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -mstack-alignment=16 -mstackrealign -fcolor-diagnostics -B/home/maximus/workspaces/work/webrtc/webrtc-checkout/src/third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin -Wheader-hygiene -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wstring-conversion -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-strict-overflow -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wthread-safety -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-strict-overflow -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wthread-safety -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-strict-overflow -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wthread-safety -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-strict-overflow -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wthread-safety -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -mmmx -m32 --sysroot=/home/maximus/workspaces/work/webrtc/webrtc-checkout/src/build/linux/debian_wheezy_i386-sysroot -O0 -g -funwind-tables -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-threadsafe-statics -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=gnu++11 -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual  -c ../../webrtc/modules/remote_bitrate_estimator/remote_bitrate_estimator_abs_send_time.cc -o obj/webrtc/modules/remote_bitrate_estimator/remote_bitrate_estimator.remote_bitrate_estimator_abs_send_time.o
../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++: 1: ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
[3/2955] CXX obj/webrtc/modules/remote_bitrate_estimator/remote_bitrate_estimator.remote_bitrate_estimator_single_stream.o
FAILED: ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -MMD -MF obj/webrtc/modules/remote_bitrate_estimator/remote_bitrate_estimator.remote_bitrate_estimator_single_stream.o.d -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -DCLD_VERSION=2 -DEXPAT_RELATIVE_PATH -DWEBRTC_POSIX -DWEBRTC_LINUX -DWEBRTC_INCLUDE_INTERNAL_AUDIO_DEVICE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=259396-1 -DUI_COMPOSITOR_IMAGE_TRANSPORT -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_PANGO=1 -DUSE_CAIRO=1 -DUSE_DEFAULT_RENDER_THEME=1 -DUSE_LIBJPEG_TURBO=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DUSE_CLIPBOARD_AURAX11=1 -DENABLE_ONE_CLICK_SIGNIN -DENABLE_WEBRTC=1 -DENABLE_MEDIA_ROUTER=1 -DENABLE_PEPPER_CDMS -DENABLE_CONFIGURATION_POLICY -DENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS -DENABLE_HIDPI=1 -DENABLE_TOPCHROME_MD=1 -DUSE_UDEV -DFIELDTRIAL_TESTING_ENABLED -DENABLE_TASK_MANAGER=1 -DENABLE_EXTENSIONS=1 -DENABLE_PDF=1 -DENABLE_PLUGINS=1 -DENABLE_SESSION_SERVICE=1 -DENABLE_THEMES=1 -DENABLE_AUTOFILL_DIALOG=1 -DENABLE_BACKGROUND=1 -DENABLE_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_BASIC_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_PRINT_PREVIEW=1 -DENABLE_SPELLCHECK=1 -DENABLE_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_DETECTION=1 -DENABLE_APP_LIST=1 -DENABLE_SETTINGS_APP=1 -DENABLE_SUPERVISED_USERS=1 -DENABLE_MDNS=1 -DENABLE_SERVICE_DISCOVERY=1 -DV8_USE_EXTERNAL_STARTUP_DATA -DFULL_SAFE_BROWSING -DSAFE_BROWSING_CSD -DSAFE_BROWSING_DB_LOCAL -DBWE_TEST_LOGGING_COMPILE_TIME_ENABLE=0 -DUSE_LIBPCI=1 -DUSE_OPENSSL=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_NSS_CERTS=1 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DWTF_USE_DYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS=1 -D_DEBUG -Igen -I../.. -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-strict-overflow -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wthread-safety -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Werror -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fvisibility=hidden -pipe -fPIC -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -mstack-alignment=16 -mstackrealign -fcolor-diagnostics -B/home/maximus/workspaces/work/webrtc/webrtc-checkout/src/third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin -Wheader-hygiene -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wstring-conversion -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-strict-overflow -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wthread-safety -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-strict-overflow -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wthread-safety -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-strict-overflow -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wthread-safety -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-strict-overflow -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wthread-safety -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -mmmx -m32 --sysroot=/home/maximus/workspaces/work/webrtc/webrtc-checkout/src/build/linux/debian_wheezy_i386-sysroot -O0 -g -funwind-tables -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-threadsafe-statics -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=gnu++11 -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual  -c ../../webrtc/modules/remote_bitrate_estimator/remote_bitrate_estimator_single_stream.cc -o obj/webrtc/modules/remote_bitrate_estimator/remote_bitrate_estimator.remote_bitrate_estimator_single_stream.o
../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++: 1: ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
[3/2955] CXX obj/webrtc/modules/remote_bitrate_estimator/remote_bitrate_estimator.remote_estimator_proxy.o
FAILED: ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -MMD -MF obj/webrtc/modules/remote_bitrate_estimator/remote_bitrate_estimator.remote_estimator_proxy.o.d -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -DCLD_VERSION=2 -DEXPAT_RELATIVE_PATH -DWEBRTC_POSIX -DWEBRTC_LINUX -DWEBRTC_INCLUDE_INTERNAL_AUDIO_DEVICE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=259396-1 -DUI_COMPOSITOR_IMAGE_TRANSPORT -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_PANGO=1 -DUSE_CAIRO=1 -DUSE_DEFAULT_RENDER_THEME=1 -DUSE_LIBJPEG_TURBO=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DUSE_CLIPBOARD_AURAX11=1 -DENABLE_ONE_CLICK_SIGNIN -DENABLE_WEBRTC=1 -DENABLE_MEDIA_ROUTER=1 -DENABLE_PEPPER_CDMS -DENABLE_CONFIGURATION_POLICY -DENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS -DENABLE_HIDPI=1 -DENABLE_TOPCHROME_MD=1 -DUSE_UDEV -DFIELDTRIAL_TESTING_ENABLED -DENABLE_TASK_MANAGER=1 -DENABLE_EXTENSIONS=1 -DENABLE_PDF=1 -DENABLE_PLUGINS=1 -DENABLE_SESSION_SERVICE=1 -DENABLE_THEMES=1 -DENABLE_AUTOFILL_DIALOG=1 -DENABLE_BACKGROUND=1 -DENABLE_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_BASIC_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_PRINT_PREVIEW=1 -DENABLE_SPELLCHECK=1 -DENABLE_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_DETECTION=1 -DENABLE_APP_LIST=1 -DENABLE_SETTINGS_APP=1 -DENABLE_SUPERVISED_USERS=1 -DENABLE_MDNS=1 -DENABLE_SERVICE_DISCOVERY=1 -DV8_USE_EXTERNAL_STARTUP_DATA -DFULL_SAFE_BROWSING -DSAFE_BROWSING_CSD -DSAFE_BROWSING_DB_LOCAL -DBWE_TEST_LOGGING_COMPILE_TIME_ENABLE=0 -DUSE_LIBPCI=1 -DUSE_OPENSSL=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_NSS_CERTS=1 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DWTF_USE_DYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS=1 -D_DEBUG -Igen -I../.. -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-strict-overflow -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wthread-safety -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Werror -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fvisibility=hidden -pipe -fPIC -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -mstack-alignment=16 -mstackrealign -fcolor-diagnostics -B/home/maximus/workspaces/work/webrtc/webrtc-checkout/src/third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin -Wheader-hygiene -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wstring-conversion -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-strict-overflow -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wthread-safety -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-strict-overflow -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wthread-safety -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-strict-overflow -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wthread-safety -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-strict-overflow -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wthread-safety -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -mmmx -m32 --sysroot=/home/maximus/workspaces/work/webrtc/webrtc-checkout/src/build/linux/debian_wheezy_i386-sysroot -O0 -g -funwind-tables -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-threadsafe-statics -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=gnu++11 -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual  -c ../../webrtc/modules/remote_bitrate_estimator/remote_estimator_proxy.cc -o obj/webrtc/modules/remote_bitrate_estimator/remote_bitrate_estimator.remote_estimator_proxy.o
../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++: 1: ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed. ``

Comment: Can you post the errors in detail.

Comment: @spicyramen, done! Thanks to this (and you), I have noticed line `-B/home/maximus/workspaces/work/webrtc/webrtc-checkout/src/third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin` and it seems to me stange.

Comment: did you solved it @LexSergeev??

Comment: @Explore, no I haven't solved it ): I have left this

Comment: ok  thanks for your reply @LexSergeev

Comment: Please visit this article which is quite helpful for webrtc native development as well as compilation of webrtc native stack. [compilation_of_webRtc_Library](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Compile_WebRTC_Library_For_Android)

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this article](http://technicaladventure.blogspot.com.eg/2017/10/compiling-webrtc-on-ubuntu.html) I described how to build WebRTC straigh forward.

**Download script & Run** 
https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/build/install-build-deps.sh

```
./build/install-build-deps.sh  --no-chromeos-fonts
```

`$ git clone --depth 1` https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git

```
$ export PATH=`pwd`/depot_tools:"$PATH"
```

**Define Building Parameters**

```
$ export GYP_DEFINES="target_arch=x64 host_arch=x64 build_with_chromium=0 use_openssl=0 use_gtk=0 use_x11=0 include_examples=0 include_tests=1 fastbuild=1 remove_webcore_debug_symbols=1 include_pulse_audio=0 include_internal_video_render=0 clang=1 "
```

**Download Source Code**

```
$ mkdir webrtc-checkout
$ cd webrtc-checkout

$ gclient config https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc.git@branch-heads/50 --name=src
$ gclient sync --force --with_branch_heads 
$ gclient sync --force --with_branch_heads --nohooks 

$ cd src

$ git checkout branch-heads/50
```

**Generate Build Script**

```
 $ rm -rf ./out/
 $ gclient runhooks
```

**Compile**

```
$ ninja -C ./out/Release
```

**Now Generate Full Libs & Headers**

```
$ mkdir ../lib/
$ find  ./ -name "*.o" -and -not -name do_not_use -and -not -name protoc -and -not -name genperf -exec ar crs ../lib/libwebrtc.a {} +

$ mkdir ../include
$ find ./ -name *.h -exec cp --parents '{}' ../include ';'
```